# Duplicate folder into new folder one level up in the directionary

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, shutil

I have a folder (1.0) which I want to duplicate one the folder one level up the directory.
For example:
C:\Users\remco\Downloads\stikstof-master\1.0
I either want the folder (1.0) or all the files within the folder (20 files) to get copied to:
C:\Users\remco\Downloads\stikstof-master#
Please note that the 2.0 folder is still non existent

I managed to get the current file path using the following code:

```
from utils import os
import shutil
file_path = os.getcwd()
print (file_path)
```

I tried some things within the os and shutil packages however I was just unable to get it working.

Comment: Show the code you've tried and tell us what went wrong

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import shutil

source_path = r'C:\Users\remco\Downloads\stikstof-master\1.0'
destination_path = r'C:\Users\remco\Downloads\stikstof-master'

try:
    shutil.copytree(source_path, destination_path, dirs_exist_ok=True)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error occurred while copying directory: {e}")
```